# tableview expand collapse issue with JSON Data

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

i am creating `Swift` app and inside app i am implementing `UITableView` Collapse/Expand functionality and i am setting up static data in tableview and its displaying successfully but when i a trying to load `JSON` than i am facing issue here is my code and model structure

here is the model to parse `JSON`

```
public struct Item {
    var service: String
    var service_price: Int
    var barber_service_id: Int
    var service_duration: Int
    
    public init(service: String, service_price: Int,barber_service_id: Int,service_duration: Int) {
        self.service = service
        self.service_price = service_price
        self.barber_service_id = barber_service_id
        self.service_duration = service_duration
    }
}
public struct Section1 {
    var name: String
    var items: [Item]
    var collapsed: Bool
    
    public init(name: String, items: [Item], collapsed: Bool = false) {
        self.name = name
        self.items = items
        self.collapsed = collapsed
    }
}
```

Here is the way i am populating tableview with static data

```
public var sectionsData: [Section1] = [
    Section1(name: "Beard", items: [Item(service: "Beard Trim", service_price: 1, barber_service_id: 1, service_duration: 30),Item(service: "Beard Line Up", service_price: 1, barber_service_id: 1, service_duration: 30)], collapsed: true)
]
```

as you can se in static code i have added Two items in `Item` array and now here is my code from which i am trying to implementing with `JSON` data

```
service.array?.forEach({ (sList) in
       let item = Item(service: sList["service"].stringValue, service_price: sList["service_price"].intValue, barber_service_id: sList["barber_service_id"].intValue, service_duration: sList["service_duration"].intValue)
       let sections = Section1(name: category_name, items: [item], collapsed: true)
       self.sections.append(sections)
})
```

as you can see in my code i am fetch `JSON` data with for each loop but now as in static code i am able to add multiple items so how to do it when in dynamic data

can anyone help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Create a instance var to hold your data source.

```
var sectionsData: [Section1] = []
```

Create section(s) from API response

```
guard let array = service.array else {
    return
}

let newSections: [Section1] = array.map { (sList) in
    let item = Item(service: sList["service"].stringValue, service_price: sList["service_price"].intValue, barber_service_id: sList["barber_service_id"].intValue, service_duration: sList["service_duration"].intValue)
    return Section1(name: category_name, items: [item], collapsed: true)
}
```

Add this new data to your instance var

```
sectionsData.append(contentsOf: newSections)
```

Reload table data (on main thread)

Comment: Thanks but i am getting error after trying your code `Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred` see i have edited your answer where i am getting error

Comment: Sorry I wrote this code on stackoverflow. Add type for newSections. I will update code.

Comment: Okay i am trying to search about it but not able to solve this error please help me on this

Comment: again i am getting this error `Value of optional type '[Section1]?' must be unwrapped to a value of type '[Section1]'`

Comment: also getting this error after using map `Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'String'`

Comment: Error for Value of optional is because service.array is optional.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220912/discussion-between-k-thorat-and-gipeje).

Comment: yes now error for optional value solved but still i am getting `Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'String'` this error